# sparkML load model from Azure storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, cloud, azure-storage, apache-spark-ml

I have spark scala application. the app is using model(sparkML) to test some data frame.
I want to load the model from Azure blob storage with service principal security.

define spark session config:
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.blob.core.windows.net ="OAuth"
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type..blob.core.windows.net
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id..blob.core.windows.net
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret..blob.core.windows.net

and loading the model :
PipelineModel.load("wasbs://@.blob.core.windows.net/")

try to define all spark session configuration and run the load method